# Is there a way to run automation tests on Edge Browser on robot framework with selenium+python running on Docker Image built on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, ui-automation, rpa

My automation project is built on robot framework with selenium webdriver library and python. I want to run my automation tests on Edge browser but it shows 'No Browser is Open' error every time.

I am using msedge.selenium_tools for edge and selenium version is 3.141.0. I am trying to run this on Docker image built on Ubuntu. I have placed all the required dependencies as well.

I have set the required ENV variables as well. Please see the attached.

I have tried this with selenium 4.0 as well as it provides in built edge browser support but in that case as well it shows same error.

[Docker File - Edge Browser dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw3c1.png)

[Browser.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQYYa.png)

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZuX5.png)

I am using msedge.selenium_tools for edge and selenium version is 3.141.0. I am trying to run this on Docker image built on Ubuntu.

I have placed all the required dependencies as well. I have set the required ENV variables as well. Please see the attached.

I have tried this with selenium 4.0 as well as it provides in built edge browser support but in that case as well it shows same error.